# как добавить загрузчик в ckedior

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

Я хочу добавлять картинку в форму редактирования текста

Проблема в том что я не могу добавить картинку с компа, нету загрузчка

Как парвильно добавить данный функционал(загрузчик)
я использовал как описано здеь https://lan143.ru/blog/posts/zagruzka-kartinok-cerez-ckeditor-v-yii-2

мой код:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(CKEditor::className(),[
        'editorOptions' => [
            // 'preset' => 'basic', //разработанны стандартные настройки basic, standard, full данную возможность не обязательно использовать
            'inline' => false, //по умолчанию false
            'toolbarGroups' => [
                ['name' => 'basicstyles', 'groups' => ['basicstyles']],
                ['name' => 'paragraph', 'groups' => ['list', 'indent', 'align']],
                ['name' => 'links'],
                ['name' => 'insert'],
            ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                'filebrowserImageUploadUrl' => 'allproblems/problems/Upload'
            ]
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

файловая структура
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На сайте Yii Framework есть неплохая документация: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload